# How to calculate area under the curve for multiple geom_line objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, auc

I have a large series of time-course data with various treatments and wish to calculate the area under the curve for each plotted variable.

I've managed to plot the data in ggplot after aggregating the data to get the means/stdev/sem for each particular condition at each timepoint.  I have tried using plotROC to calculate auc but I think my code or the way my data are structured are preventing me from calculating this as I keep getting error messages.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=Mean, colour=IR, group=as.numeric(IR))) +
  geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= Mean-SEM, ymax= Mean+SEM)) +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Time post IR (hours)") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0), breaks = c(0, 24, 48, 72)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Dose",
                      values=c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

When I add `geom_roc()` to the code, I get this message:

> ```
> Error in if (slev[2] == 0 & slev[2] == 1) return(D) : missing value
> where TRUE/FALSE needed
> ```

I'm fairly new to this type of analysis so would appreciate any help/advice for using ggplot to do this.  Ideally, I would like to be able to calculate AUCs for both lines and insert the calculated aucs within the plots themselves.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need to see the data, put head(data)